# First order partial diff. equation, problem with Cauchy problem

Tags: partial-differential-equations

I have problems solving this trivial pde:

$$x_1 u_{x_1} = 2 x_2$$

$$u(x,0)=g(x), \ g: \mathbb{R} \rightarrow \mathbb{R}, C^1$$

The solution satisfying the first equation seems to be $u(x_1,x_2)= 2 x_2 \log x_1 + C$

But then $u(x,0) = C$

Could you tell me what I am doing wrong? The solution must be dependent on $g$! And I don't see my mistake.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The solution of the differential equation is correct, however $C$ is a function of $x_2$ i.e. $C=C(x_2)$.